# How to use a for loop with multiple results

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, indexing

I have to automate this sequence of functions:

```
for (i in c(15,17,20,24,25,26,27,28,29,45,50,52,55,60,62)) {

WBES_sf_angola_i <- subset(WBES_sf_angola, isic == i)
WBES_angola_i <- as_Spatial(WBES_sf_angola_i)             

FDI_angola_i <- FDI_angola[FDI_angola$isic==i,]           

dist_ao_i <- distm(WBES_angola_i,FDI_angola_i, fun = distGeo)/1000    

rm(WBES_sf_angola_i,WBES_angola_i,FDI_angola_i)
}
```

As a result, I want a "dist_ao" for each i. The indexed values are to be found in the  `isic` columns of the  `WBES_sf_angola` and the  `FDI_angola` datasets.

How can I embed the index in the various items' names?

**EDIT:**

I tried with following modification:

```
for (i in c(15,17,20,24,25,26,27,28,29,45,50,52,55,60,62)) {

WBES_sf_angola_i <- subset(WBES_sf_angola, isic == i)
WBES_angola_i <- as_Spatial(WBES_sf_angola_i)             

FDI_angola_i <- FDI_angola[FDI_angola$isic==i,]           

result_list <- list()
  
result_list[[paste0("dist_ao_", i)]] <-  distm(WBES_angola_i,FDI_angola_i, fun = distGeo)/1000  

rm(WBES_sf_angola_i,WBES_angola_i,FDI_angola_i)
}
```

and the output is just a list of 1 that contains `dist_ao_62`. Where do I avoid overwriting?

Comment: You could put the dist_ao_ elements in a named list (ie.e. `result_list <- list(); result_list[[paste0("dist_ao_", i)]] <-  distm(WBES_angola_i,FDI_angola_i, fun = distGeo)/1000   ` Alternatively (and not really recommended) you could use `assign`

Comment: Ok. Is the rest of the items indexed in the right way?  I mean, if for each value of i I want different `WBES_sf_angola_i `, `WBES_angola_i ` and `FDI_angola_i `, is this the way I should index them?

Comment: In your current code the variable `WBES_sf_angola_i` is going to be overwritten on each iteration of the loop (i.e. there is only a variable named `WBES_sf_angola_i`, whose last letter "i" is never going to be replaced with the current value of the iterator `i`!) If you want to dynamically create the names you have to use something along the `paste()` path....

Comment: See the edited question. Should I use `paste()` for each element of the loop?

Comment: In your edited question you overwrite `result_list` on each iteration. You should move it out of the loop ;)

Comment: I've added the corrected code below as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested (due to missing MRE) but should work:

```
result_list <- list()

for (i in c(15,17,20,24,25,26,27,28,29,45,50,52,55,60,62)) {

  result_list[[paste0("dist_ao_", i)]] <-  distm(as_Spatial(subset(WBES_sf_angola, isic == i))  , FDI_angola[FDI_angola$isic==i,], fun = distGeo)/1000  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could approach it this way. All resulting `dataframes` will be included in the `list`, which you can convert to a `dataframe` from the last line of the the code here. NOTE: since not reproducible, I have mostly taken the code from your question inside the loop.

```
WBES_sf_angola_result <- list() # renamed this, as it seems you are using a dataset with the name WBES_sf_angola
WBES_angola <- list()
FDI_angola <- list()
dist_ao <- list()


for (i in c(15,17,20,24,25,26,27,28,29,45,50,52,55,60,62)) {
  
  WBES_sf_angola[[paste0("i_", i)]] <- subset(WBES_sf_angola, isic == i)
  WBES_angola[[paste0("i_", i)] <- as_Spatial(WBES_sf_angola_i)             
  
  FDI_angola[[paste0("i_", i)] <- FDI_angola[FDI_angola$isic==i,]           
  
  dist_ao[[paste0("i_", i)] <- distm(WBES_angola_i,FDI_angola_i, fun = distGeo)/1000    
  
  rm(WBES_sf_angola_i,WBES_angola_i,FDI_angola_i)
}

WBES_sf_angola_result <- do.call(rbind, WBES_sf_angola_result) # to get a dataframe
```

Your subset data can also be accessed through list index. eg.

```
WBES_sf_angola_result[[i_15]] # for the first item.
```

Comment: I tried. It returns an error: `Error in subset.default(WBES_sf_angola, isic == i) : 
  object 'isic' not found`

Comment: @nflore Don't you need to specifically mention, `WBES_sf_angola$isic` in subset